# Unable to find the custom Pipeline for promoting File name at the receive location

Tags: pipeline, biztalk, biztalk-2016

[Custom Receive Pipeline Component to Promote File name](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23527.custom-receive-pipeline-component-to-promote-file-name.aspx) is the custom code I used.

But when I build and deploy it. send a copy of the pipeline to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2016\Pipeline Components. Then I can't see the pipeline in Toolbox.

Am I doing something wrong?

Should I make any changes in the pipeline?

How should I receive the desired output?

Why am I using a custom pipeline line is the receive location using pass-through receive?

Comment: Cant find the pipeline in tolbox

Comment: Do you need the File Name for routing?  Because the file name will be a non-promoted property in the message context already without a custom component.  If you don't need it for routing you don't even need a custom pipeline component.

Comment: Yes correct.  I need for routing the message

Comment: @Dijkgraaf i need the pipeline to route the messages . And so i need a filename as a promoted property